# Chrome, Export html table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome is missing ability to export html table to Excel like Internet Explorer have. Is there any workaround for this?

I think that might be quite easy to select part of text in table and loop with Javascript and get the table without knowing table class name.

Comment: IMHO it would be easy to export a CSV but not an excel file.

Comment: What Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somekind partial solution is this bookmarklet which takes table data by selection, converts it to csv and add whole thing to textarea below the original table.

https://gist.github.com/poezn/4278379

Answer (score 0):

For the 2022 reader. There are a few Chrome extensions available to do this.

[Table Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-capture/iebpjdmgckacbodjpijphcplhebcmeop/related?hl=en) works pretty well. There's a paid feature to export to CSV, but I just use copy to clipboard (which is CSV data) then paste into a text file, and name my-table.csv.